# "Ghost rectangle" affecting program?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, frameworks

Yesterday there was a rectangle stuck in the top corner of my program, and for some reason no matter what I did I could not get it out of there. Today I re-ran the program, and it disappeared, but I believe it's memory is still stuck because it's affecting my code.

I'm trying to detect when rectangle A (motioned by accelerometer) contacts rectangle B (randomly placed; motionless). Nothing happens when A contacts B, however when I move A into the top corner where the ghost rectangle was all of yesterday it runs my if statement continuously until I move it away.

Here is the code just incase it's needed

```
@synthesize Button;
@synthesize Rand;
//Awaking the accelerometer
-(void) awakeaccelerometer
{
    [[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer]setUpdateInterval:1.0/50.0];//<---Sensitivity
    [[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer]setDelegate:self];

    NSLog(@"Accelerometer is awake");

    float randX = arc4random() % 320;
    float randY = arc4random() % 548;

    CGPoint randNewPlace = CGPointMake(randX, randY);
    Rand.center = randNewPlace;

}


//Controlling the accelerometer
-(void) accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration
{
#define MovingObjectRadius 4

    //Acceleration for player
    valueX = acceleration.x * 10; //speeds
    valueY = acceleration.y * -10; //speeds



    //Create new integers
    int newX = (int)(Button.center.x + valueX);
    int newY = (int)(Button.center.y + valueY);


    //Position Validate...This stops the movements from going past the screen; 320 pixels
    //For X
    if (newX > (320 - MovingObjectRadius))
    {
        newX = (320 - MovingObjectRadius);
    }

    if (newX < (0 + MovingObjectRadius))
    {
        newX = (0 + MovingObjectRadius);
    }

    //For Y
    if (newY > (548 - MovingObjectRadius))
    {
        newY = (548 - MovingObjectRadius);
    }

    if (newY < (0 + MovingObjectRadius))
    {
        newY = (0 + MovingObjectRadius);
    }



    //Make the new point
    CGPoint buttonNewCenter = CGPointMake(newX,newY);
    Button.center = buttonNewCenter;


    CGRect blockRect = CGRectMake(newX, newY, 20, 20);
    CGRect targetRect = CGRectMake(randX, randY, 20, 20);

    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(blockRect, targetRect))
        {
            float tnewX = arc4random() % 320;
            float tnewY = arc4random() % 548;

            CGPoint randNewPl = CGPointMake(tnewX, tnewY);
            Rand.center = randNewPl;
        }
}
```

Comment: a ghost rectangle? sounds like you need an exorcist? Have you tried asking on http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/about ?

Comment: Hah. Yeah. But really there isn't anything in the top corner but every time I run the program my if statement plays like a loop (aka saying that two rectangles are contacting...), until I move the block away. There was a block stuck there all of yesterday in the same position, and around the same exact dimensions it seems as well..

Comment: Do you by any chance mean "calls the `accelerometer: didAccelerate:` method" instead of "runs your if statement"?